# How to prevent Windows Defender from restarting automatically in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, windows-defender

Windows 10 only allows to turn off the Windows Defender temporarily. Is there a way to revert this back to the old manual behavior?

I don't want to disable it completely, I just don't like the automatic restart.

Comment: The term, "turn off" could mean many things.  What exactly do you want Defender to do, at different times, and for each time, why?  There is the UI, the tray, and the services, which each appear at different times.

Comment: I mean the real-time protection option under Settings > Windows Defender > Real-Time protection. Sometimes for I/O intensive work I find it's faster without the protection. It's very annoying to check every few minutes if it's turned on again by itself.